# какой способ более затратный, почему ,чем они отличаются. Получение изображения из drawable или из assets

Tags: java, android

```
mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.touch);
```

или

```
       try{
            InputStream  ims    = mAssetManager.open("touch.png");
            field = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ims);
        }
        catch (IOException ex){
            return;
        }
```

В документации написано, что в папках drawable изображения могут быть оптимизированы. Чтобы не было оптимизации положите их в res/raw. Я попробовал и в raw и в assets и получил в итоге один и тот же битмап. Наверно изображение в drawable в моем случае не было оптимизировано. А если бы было оптимизировано, получил бы я битмап меньшего размера (в байтах)?

Comment: В играх обычно применяют assets, в UI применяют resources, просто потому что UI-библиотека Android лучше подходит для работы с ресурсами, а игры пишут на C++ и там библиотекой является NDK и в нем, наоборот, есть AAssetManager но нет для ресурсов, ну, а преждевременная оптимизация это одна из форм перфекционизма, зла которое губит проект на стадии стартапа, те кто ею страдает живет не долго и вряд ли успеет вам ответить. :)

Comment: Нет нет , ну постойте, не надо говорить , что игры пишут на C++ , а как же куча игр написанные на java движках, да даже на комп столько всего на java написано. Ну  я понял ваши слова так: изображения в drawable разбиты по плотностям экрана, если брать из assets, то там много возни с подгонкой размеров. Только вот не пойму , вы говорите в играх применяют assets, ну и почему в андроид их применяют,если библиотека плохая? или вы это говорите потому что считаете что игры пишут только на C++ ?

Comment: Включите мозг и читайте еще раз. Есть две библиотеки, не одна, а две. Для игр одна библиотека - NDK и C++, а для UI - другая - Android API и Java. И вот в первой удобнее с ассетами, а во второй с drawable. Отсюда получается, что в играх лучше ассеты, в UI - drawable. Теперь дошло, или еще раз повторить? Если дошло - слава Богу. Далее, вы утверждаете, что есть куча игр, написанных на Java, а не на NDK и C++ с их ассетами. Если это так, то вывод про ассеты и drawable не верен. Но где эта куча? Приведите хоть 2-3 игры для Android на Java.

Comment: Скорее всего Rou1997 имел ввиду что в фрэймворках используются прослойки на С++ которые добавляют в производительности. Ну и опять же оптимизация должна происходить в улучшении алгоритмов и избавление от антипаттернов а не переписывании кусков кода на С++ или ассемблере(это уже крайние меры)

Comment: @alexandrgaiduchok В каких еще фреймворках? Не надо додумывать за меня. Я писал то, что я писал: игры для Android целиком пишутся на C++. Я это знаю, поскольку занимался их реверс-инжинирингом.

Comment: @Rou1997 т.е вы провели реверс инжиниринг всех игр из маркета чтобы с такой уверенностью утверждать что все игры пишутся на с++? А что на счет Unity, libgdx?

Comment: @temq Зачем всех, включая пятнашки и крестики-нолики с 1.5 скачиваниями в месяц, что за прямолинейность. Вообще вы меня все утомили здесь, а ответ прост как апельсин, стоит использовать то, что удобно в данном случае, используете какой-то "движок" и в нем предусмотрено использование ассетов - используйте ассеты, если drwb то drwb, если не используете "движок" а пишете сами на C++ NDK (а писать надо на C++ NDK, а не Java) то ассеты, все, ухожу, найдете примеры популярных игр для androdi на Java - пишите.

Comment: Я не использую никаких движков и пишу на java и есть возможность использовать и assets и drawable . А вопрос задан в попытке понять как проходит раскодирование изображений из различных директорий. Есть изображение уже в bmp  с плавным градиентом, а после того как его беру из  assets градиент становится резким, хотя на сколько я понимаю bmp декодировке уже не должно подвергаться. А игры  часто проскакивают Unity, а он написан на C/C++ , так же как и движок unreal. Пока что не так важно на чем пишутся игры, в java порог вхождения ниже. То что надо человеку,который не учился на программиста.

Comment: При установке изображения на фон оно "подгоняется" под размер этого фона - при этом и может происходить искажение, если размеры не равны ПОПИКСЕЛЬНО

Comment: Думаю вы не правы. В зависости от плотности пикселей выбирается изображение из той или иной папки и только оптимизируется, но не подгоняется. А еще есть папка raw из которой ресурсы даже не оптимизируются.  К тому же изоббражение попиксельно совпадает и даже пробовал в ресурс ставить bmp изображение,  т.е. которое и декодировке не должно подвергаться,  но все равно градиент становится резким.  А bmp в ресурсах и в оперативке занимает одинаковый объем памяти. И качество ARGB8888